# Bad:PageSpeed Insights can't work by using http,it works when I using https

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTfO1.png)

it can't work by using http,it works when I using https.

I haven't configured my server to handle any specific user-agent

PageSpeed Insights  only support https now?  or only support http2 ?  or Deprecate HTTP/1.1 ? or other reason.

i change user-agent the same to pageSpeed in my brower ,using http it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your web server may be [geo-blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo-blocking) ([Japanese translation](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B8%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%AD%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0)) traffic from outside of Japan.

When I try to visit http://www.yabusanitary.com/ from my computer in the US, the request times out.

I set up three tests using WebPageTest to visit the page from three countries: [the US, Ireland, and Japan](https://www.webpagetest.org/video/compare.php?tests=240118_AiDcG9_VT-l:USA%2C240118_BiDc8J_XE-l:Ireland%2C240118_BiDcXK_XD-l:Japan&thumbSize=200&ival=5000&end=doc). The filmstrip comparison shows that the page only loads successfully when the request comes from within Japan:

[image]

PageSpeed Insights runs from Google data centers around the world, so it seems like your web server is blocking the tool from testing your page, just like in the non-Japan tests above.

Comment: Previously, during my testing, the configuration was as follows: the domain was resolved to AWS CDN, and AWS routed through dedicated lines back to nodes in Los Angeles and Hong Kong. When tested with HTTP, an error occurred, but the browser could still open the page. Yesterday, my operations colleague directly resolved the domain to the China node. This likely caused the issue where only Japan could be accessed during testing. Now, even with the browser, I cannot open the page..

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, which informed me that PageSpeed Insights does not impose restrictions on HTTP during testing, nor does it limit the HTTP request protocols to 1, 2, or 3. My problem should be related to the CDN or DNS provider